# Why permission denied error with flags password/locahost in PostgreSQL?

Tags: linux, postgresql, shell, file-permissions

The database *detector* exists, verified by `\l` in psql.
The user `postgres` exists verified by `SELECT * FROM pg_user;`.

## #1 test [solved]

I run

```
sudo -u postgres psql detector -c "SELECT * FROM pg_user"
```

but get

```
could not change directory to "/home/masi/det": Permission denied
```

while getting also the right output of the user table.

**Solution in Fabricio's answer and comments** i.e. restart shell; previously run the flag `--password` causes the strange behavior.

## #2 test [solved]

Other strange test. I run

```
sudo -u postgres psql detector --password -h localhost -c 'SELECT * FROM pg_user;'
```

which gives the following although I am the localhost.

```
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

**Solution in Fabricio's answer and comments** i.e. restart shell and do not use the flag `--password` with sudo.
Do not use the flag `-h localhost` with sudo.

Why here is the permission denied error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're in `/home/masi/det_78_2015` when launching the psql command. Since the user launching the command is postgres, it is not allowed to view the current home directory you are in. This is why the command is successful but it is throwing an error regarding the permissions of the directory.

Does the`postgres` user have a home directory in the system?

Comment: Sorry just typo in the body. I am at the right location. Where should the home directory be? I have not set up anything.

Comment: It doesn't really affect the query. It's just telling you that once the command is executed being postgres it cannot change to the current directory

Comment: What system are you running on?

Comment: Debian 8.1, similar to Ubuntu.

Comment: As per question you are having 2 separate problems. Te directory issue is not much. The problem lies in the authentication.

Comment: Can you explain how to proceed here, please?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I previously used the flag `--password` and running the command without it afterwards, results into such permission denied messages. Now, restarting the shell, I do not get anymore the permission denied. This is strange behavior! The flag `-h localhost` thing, still, I do not understand.

Comment: That flag specifies that you are connecting to the database on your local machine.

Comment: Yes, I am connecting to the database on my local machine but it is not working. I think just do not use the flag `-h localhost` with sudo is the solution. I presented the main problem as the test case #3. The situation from which I developed the tests 1 and 2.

Comment: The thread got too extensive. We managed to solve the challenges with the flags `--password` and `-h localhost` but not with `-c/-f` about which I opened a new thread here http://stackoverflow.com/q/31399266/54964